# restricting character set in a Textinput field

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, character, textinput, restrict

I have a TextInput field that should be restricted to either capital letters, lowercase letters, numbers and underscores. This is the code I'm trying to use to restrict characters:

```
restrict="\\A-Z\\a-z\\0-9\\ \\_\\-"
```

I'm using MXML for this Textinput component.

Unfortunately this does not restrict the \ character, which is the last character I'd like to restrict.

How can I add the backslash to the list of restricted characters?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually found the solution I've amended the restrict code to:

restrict="A-Za-z0-9 _\-"

I took out all the back slashes which I thought or was using as delimiters.

Works fine now.

Comment: Go ahead and accept your own answer! However, before you do, it looks like you've accidentally left the backslashes in in your revised code.

Comment: Yes, the answer should read: restrict="A-Za-z0-9 _\-". The last backslash escapes the dash character which if not escaped specifies a range (e.g. A-Z)

Comment: Note that if you are specifying restrict in ActionScript, you need a double-backslash. Like so: `myTextInput.restrict="A-Za-z0-9 _\\-"`